# Call to a member function extension() on null

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatable

```
 public function store(Request $post)
    {  
        $validated = $post->validate(['eId'=>'required','about'=>'required']);
        
        $edocsId = $post->id;
        
        if($edocsId){
            
            $edocs = Edocs::find($edocsId);
            
            if($post->hasFile('scan')){
                $file = time().'.'.$post->scan->extension();
                $post->scan->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
                $edocs->scan = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file;     
            }   
         }else{
            $file = time().'.'.$post->scan->extension();
            $post->scan->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
            $edocs = new Edocs;
            $edocs->scan = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file;
         }
         
        $edocs->eId = $post->eId;
        $edocs->about = $post->about;
        $edocs->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $edocs->save();
            
        return response()->json($edocs);
    }
```

Выдает эту ошибку при редактировании: `Call to a member function extension() on null`, выдает поле картинки пустым

Answer (score 0):

1. Предположу что в строчке

   $file = time().'.'.$post->scan->extension();

есть обращение к `extension()` к объекту `scan`, которого нет в объекте `$post`.

2. В коде присутствует дублирование кода - это плохо, поэтому в коде возникла эта ошибка.

   ```
   if($post->hasFile('scan')){
       $file = time().'.'.$post->scan->extension();
       $post->scan->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
       $edocs->scan = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file;     
   }
   ```
3. Чтобы этого избежать в laravel есть элегантный метод [firstOrNew](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models) тогда код станет еще и короче.

   ```
   public function store(Request $post) 
   {
       $validated = $post->validate(['eId'=>'required','about'=>'required']);
       $edocsId = $post->id;
       $edocs = Edocs::firstOrNew($edocsId);
       if($post->hasFile('scan')){
            $file = time().'.'.$post->scan->extension();
            $post->scan->storeAs('public/uploads/images',$file);
            $edocs->scan = 'storage/uploads/images/'.$file;
        }
       $edocs->eId = $post->eId;
       $edocs->about = $post->about;
       $edocs->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $edocs->save();

       return response()->json($edocs);
   }
   ```